# Oracle: Joins two tables to duplicate rows for 2 table

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have 2 tables like below:

```
Table 1
---------
   1  
   2  
   3   


 Table 2
--------    
   A   
   B   
   C
```

How do i join to get an output like below:

```
Output
---------
1 A  
1 B  
1 C  
2 A  
2 B  
2 C  
3 A  
3 B  
3 C
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `Cross join`:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Table1 
       CROSS JOIN Table2
```

You can change the order by replacing `*` with table fields.

Read more about [**Cross Join**](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.2.2/ref/rrefsqljcrossjoin.html).

**OR** you could do this:

```
SELECT Table1.*,Table2.* 
FROM Table2,Table1
```

Result:

```
ID  NAME
1   A
1   B
1   C
2   A
2   B
2   C
3   A
3   B
3   C
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to do a CROSS JOIN and that will give you the Cartesian product of all the rows.

See http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from table 1,table 2 .
```

For o/p like A 1
             A 2
             A 3
             B 1
             B 2
             B 3
             C 1
             C 2
             C 3
just